# SCSS - @media get parsed correctly

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I have the following code in my styles.scss:

```
.nav-bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 8;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;

  @media (max-width: 360px) {
    width: 320px;
  }
}
```

And this is what I see when I inspect the element in chrome:
[image]

last but not least the interesting part of my `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          {
            // This loader resolves url() and @imports inside CSS
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            // Then we apply postCSS fixes like autoprefixer and minifying
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
          },
          {
            // First we transform SASS to standard CSS
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
            },
          },
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Use your media querie seperate and out out of you css class.Now inside you media querie you can write again the different styles you want for these classes.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
 .nav-bottom {
    width: 320px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that your website uses the *SCSS*  file, but it should use the *CSS* file which is generated from that SCSS file. So I guess you should look for the line where your stylesheet is linked in the `head` and change that file reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad webpack role responsible for style. In the webpack version you showed you have to repeat loader twice 'css-loader'. Below you have the dev/prod version.

```
test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
  use: [
    mode === 'development' ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        importLoaders: 2
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
      },
    },
  ],
```